# How to automatically move a file to another PC on the network?

Tags: batch-file, file-transfer, scheduled-tasks

Here is what I am after.

I have 2 PCs connected on a network and one of them prints out an Excel spreadsheet every night to a specific folder. Is it possible to use a batch script to copy that file to the other computer on the network at a certain time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can.

- Create Batch File (Use UNC paths to copy - I recommend [RoboCopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy))
- Create Scheduled Task to call batch file at certain time

```
robocopy C:\FolderName\ \\machinename\sharedfolder "filename.ext"
```

Comment: If you don't want to use robocopy you can also map a network drive for the remote destination and then just use `copy`.

Comment: @jtb - Agreed. Robocopy is faster however and supports resuming. The only reason I suggest it. Also it is more robust when using UNC.

Answer (score 2):

Set up a scheduled task to run a program/batch file that executes a copy command.

A batch file to do that might look like

```
COPY \\server-name\path\to\file.dat C:\directory\new-location\
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a batch file / Windows scheduled task, is to use [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/freeware/) (freeware) where you can create a profile to copy your Excel spreadsheet from the source machine to the target at a specific time.

Answer (score 1):

You can save this in a .bat file. After that you can schedule it.

```
:: This is the backup 


set SourceDir=F:\XXX
set DestinyDir=I:\YYY


xcopy /e /v /y /I %SourceDir% %DestinyDir%
```

I never tested the time it takes, but it seems that xcopy is faster than the regular copy. Look what the commands do [here](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Windows [SyncToy 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) utility and then set a scheduled task along with it.